# Validation failing in IE9 using angular js

Tags: html, internet-explorer, angularjs

I am pretty new to Angular JS .Here I have a simple form as below:
**test3.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" ng-controller="Register" ng-submit="submit()" action="test2.php" method="post">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="input" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname" required>

    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="input" name="lastname" ng-model="lastname" required>

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
  <script>

  function Register($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = '';
    $scope.lastname = '';
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.submit = function() {
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  };
  }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And **test2.php:**

```
 <?php
      echo $_POST['firstname'];
 ?>
```

When I load test3.php and click on submit without filling any details, I get the message to fill the fields accordingly and the form is not submitted to test2.php. When all the details are entered properly and then if I click Submit, I see the `$_POST['firstname]` value. This works correctly in chrome and firefox.

But in IE9, there is no validation at all. On click of Submit, the form is submitted always, be the fields empty or not.

How do I make this code work in IE9 and further? The Angular JS API provides help for IE versions 8 and less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is due to the fact that `(IE < 10)` are not `HTML5` compliant with respect to client-side validation and therefore wont return true if a `"required"` attribute is present on the input element, but instead return the `(string)` attribute value.

Use `ngRequired` instead of `required` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `ngRequired` as you suggested, but its not working either.

Comment: You need to write the validation on your own for IE < 10.

Comment: Yeah. The situation is calling for it. :( Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ChetanaKestikar Why didn't you accept this answer ? Is there a remaining problem ?

Comment: As mentioned in one of my comment above, the `ngRequired` did not work for me! And I have upvoted both - the comment and answer. I guess the answer is supposed to be accepted if it has really solved my problem! Still if you need those accepted points, here you go, I accept it!