# Ng-submit ignores the submit button disabled state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy6NQ/7/): While the textbox are empty, the submit button is disabled and pressing **Enter** in the textbox does nothing as well. If you fill any text, the submit works as expected. The relevant HTML part:

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="submitData()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" required /><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" required /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy6NQ/8/), there is a strange behavior, however. When the textbox is empty, the submit button is disable, but pressing **Enter** still causes the submit function to be called. The relevant HTML part:

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="submitData()" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" required /><br />
    <br />
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The only difference between these fiddles is that the first one has 2 textboxes and the second one has a single one.

Why does it happen?

Comment: The two fiddlers are working same, What is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing it on several browsers, I successfully reproduced this bug on IE. on FF and Chrome it worked , so as you can see it's a browser/version compatibility issue so you'll probably need to handle this issue and write the validation on your own.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20542132/1745230) on stackoverflow.

Comment: I was using Chrome and had this issue. However, I had a Chrome update pending for the last couple of days, and the issue was gone after the update, so that was it. Thanks!